# Why doesn't this code trigger a ValueError?

Tags: python

I'm trying to trigger an error when the "chunk_size" is zero, or greater than the length of the "sequence." When I call this function with a chunk_size of 4, and a sequence that equals "123" it doesn't throw an error. What did I do wrong?

```
def slices(sequence,chunk_size):
    position=0
    mini_list=[]
    answer=[]

    while chunk_size<=len(sequence) and chunk_size>0:

        try:
            for char in sequence:
                if len(sequence[position:position+chunk_size])==chunk_size:
                    mini_seq = sequence[position:position+chunk_size]
                    for digit in mini_seq:
                        mini_list.append(int(digit))
                    answer.append(mini_list)
                    mini_list=[]
                    position+=1
            return answer
            break

        except ValueError:
            print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."

print slices("012", 4)
```

Comment: Which part of the code do you think should have thrown an error?

Comment: if you go out of bounds on a list - you will get an `IndexError` not `ValueError`

Comment: Also you never reach the body of the `while` since `chunk_size` will never be less or equal to 3.

Comment: @Ankit Jaiswal - "while chunk_size<=len(sequence) and chunk_size>0" should throw an error (I thought) because it evaluates to False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't throw a ValueError, because you raise it within the while block, and the while block is entered only when the required condition of `chunk_size` being `< 0` or `> len(str)` is not met.

Hence, to correct this, move the error raising part of your code out of the `while` loop. In fact, your placement of the condition within `while` is wrong, instead convert it to an `if` statement. Also, a break before a `return` statement won't make any sense.

So your code becomes

```
while True:
    try:
        if chunk_size<=len(sequence) and chunk_size>0:
            for char in sequence:
                if len(sequence[position:position+chunk_size])==chunk_size:
                    mini_seq = sequence[position:position+chunk_size]
                    for digit in mini_seq:
                        mini_list.append(int(digit))
                    answer.append(mini_list)
                    mini_list=[]
                    position+=1
            return answer
        else:
            raise ValueError       
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

Further, instead of raising an error to validate whether the data is in the right format, you can do away with raising the exception itself, and achive the same result with a simple if-else block:

```
while True:
    if chunk_size<=len(sequence) and chunk_size>0:
        for char in sequence:
            if len(sequence[position:position+chunk_size])==chunk_size:
                mini_seq = sequence[position:position+chunk_size]
                for digit in mini_seq:
                    mini_list.append(int(digit))
                answer.append(mini_list)
                mini_list=[]
                position+=1
        return answer
    else:
        print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

Comment: @ Mu, and all: I just realized how bloody stupid I was being.